# Как лучше организовать ajax запрос на web-сервер?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Есть web-сраница на жёстком диске. При её открытии необходимо сделать автоматический запрос на сервер и те данные, что возвратятся, вывести на эту страницу. Данные возвращаться должны с типом html.

Вот два варианта какие пришли в голову, но ни один не работает. В чём может быть причина?

**Вариант 1:**

```
$("#id").load('http://sitename.ru/file.php');
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://sitename.ru/file.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#id").html(data)
    }
});
```

Если же запускаю этот файл на сервере, то всё работает.

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)?

Comment: Дык, так для работы аякса и нужен сервер просто открыв файл с локального диска он работать не будет

Comment: @mccrush, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Какие ошибки? В js-консоли что пишит? Логи сервера? Факты, давайте факты!

Comment: да, мне вот тоже интересно, что возвращает в ответе `file.php`

Comment: Абсолютно фиолетово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А кроссдоменные заголовки добавили?
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *